# what is the difference between AddRegistry and IncludeRegistry in StructureMap?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, structuremap

The `Registry` class in StructureMap has an `IncludeRegistry<T>() where T : Registry, new()` method which can be used when creating a new registry instance, such as:

```
class MyRegistry : Registry
{
    public MyRegistry ()
    {
        IncludeRegistry<AnotherRegistry>();
        //For<>(...).Use<>(...); ... etc
    }
}
```

The `ConfigurationExpression` class, which inherits from `Registry`, has a `AddRegistry<T>() where T : Registry, new()` method in addition to that.

What are the (practical) differences between them and which one should I prefer when creating a container such as:

```
var myContainer = new Container(conf =>
{
    conf.AddRegistry<RegistryA>();
    conf.IncludeRegistry<RegistryB>();
});
```

I couldn't find any description of the differences in StructureMap documentation, so I'd appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IncludeRegistry` is intended to be used with a registry, to import the content of another registry.

The [XML documentation](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/da0a94750ba4a1d0f91520e44d2caeec24bff7f3/src/StructureMap.Shared/Registry.cs) for the method in `Registry` says:

> Imports the configuration from another registry into this registry

[Here](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/registry-dsl/) is an example of that from the documentation:

```
var registry = new Registry();
registry.IncludeRegistry<YellowBlueRegistry>();
```

---

`AddRegistry` is used in the configuration expression when configuring a container. It creates (when using the generic overload) a registry and imports the configuration from it to the container.

The [XML documentation](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/da0a94750ba4a1d0f91520e44d2caeec24bff7f3/src/StructureMap.Shared/ConfigurationExpression.cs) for `ConfigurationExpression::AddRegistry<T>` says:

> Creates and adds a Registry object of type T

[Here](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/) is an example of that from the documentation:

```
var container2 = new Container(c => { c.AddRegistry<FooBarRegistry>(); });
```

What makes it confusing is that `ConfigurationExpression` inherits `Registry` and thus has both those methods.

---

So in short, for container configuration (as per the documentation and test cases), you should use:

```
var myContainer = new Container(conf =>
{
    conf.AddRegistry<RegistryA>();
});
```

**Edit:**

Jeremy's reply when asking was:

> Had to look at the code. It's unlikely that you'd see any difference
>   in behavior, but `AddRegistry` should have been removed for 4. I
>   recommend you only use IncludeRegistry

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure it really addresses my question. I understand where both those methods come from (one from `Registry`, the other from `ConfigurationExpression`). But since `ConfigurationExpression` **is** a `Registry`, shouldn't both methods have the same **final effect on the constructed object graph** (the docs don't elaborate on that, or at least I can't see it)? This is what I'm trying to find out, if there are any (practical) differences and if using `IncludeRegistry` when configuring a container can cause any undesirable effects.

Comment: They have different implementations, but I didn't dig through the source code enough to see what the implications would be to use the wrong method in a scenario. The safest bet would be to follow the examples. The source of each of the implementations are available through my links above. I'm sorry I couldn't aid you more.

Comment: Jeremy commented on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/structuremap/structuremap). See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to ask around. What could be a better answer than from Jeremy himself?